# How do I generate data with Tensorflow, if I have a bunch of example?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I Am an absolute beginner with Tensorflow. I have searched, but did not found how to do this:

If I have a list of strings like this:

```
["sentace1", "...", "sentance5000"]
```

> How do I train a neural network to create similar sentences? What is the logic of generating data, text, images?  Can someone explain to me using code, through this relatively basic example?

Also, If I'd add more layers and different types of data, could it create for example pictures or music?

**A thousand thanks :)**

Comment: Please, if you downvote it consider commenting why you did that.

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I see. Then how should I re-phrase the question? I'm clueless about how to start this project.

Comment: rephrase it such that it adheres to the guidelines of SO. You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generation of music and text differs form generation of images. Text and music generation can be done with sequence models (LSTM, RNN, GRU etc), while image generation can be done with [GAN - Generative Adversarial Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661)

*Text generation:*
For text generation, first step is to create [embeddings](https://blogs.oracle.com/datascience/introduction-to-embedding-in-natural-language-processing) form your sentence either from pre-trained embedding models (word2vec, GloVe etc) then apply this embedding to your sentences. There are several other embedding techniques that you can explore.

Next step is to fit your embedded features to a sequence model. Probably [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) one you can refer as starting point.

Music generation:
[Music generation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01620) can be done with sequence models, difference being instead of sequence of words you have sound waveform, spectrogram, note, chord etc. 

Image generation:
This one is different then above two.

> We propose a new framework for estimating generative models via an adversarial process, in which we simultaneously train two models: a generative model G that captures the data distribution, and a discriminative model D that estimates the probability that a sample came from the training data rather than G. The training procedure for G is to maximize the probability of D making a mistake. 
> https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661

Coming to your questions:

> If I'd add more layers and different types of data, could it create for example pictures or music?

As stated, music and text generation can be done with similar type of network architecture (as both follows a sequence), while images needs to be treated differently.

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me with the exact code, to for instance build that sentence generator? I' really in need of help.

Comment: That becomes difficult without actually knowing how your sentences looks like.

Comment: If the sentences are like this: "This is an apple", "That is a tower", "My name is Robert", "I love chocolate"

Comment: you can follow the blog link I have provided above, It has similar example with codes.

Answer (score 3):

Popular model for generating data in natural language processing is word2vec. It encodes words to vector space, then similar words to given can be generated. Basicly you can vectorise almost anything so variation you are looking for is sentence2vec which works similar but you give sentence as input and it encodes sentences to vectors.

Here is tutorial for tensorflow: tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/word2vec

You can also try gensim implementation of w2v:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

About:

> Also, If I'd add more layers and different types of data, could it
>   create for example pictures or music?

For generating images you should read about Auto Encoders (eg. VAE) and Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs). These architectures works different from NLP architectures.

Comment: @BudaÖrs I'm sorry. I thought question is just about data. Are you asking for specific model, you want to create model from scratch? Please divide question to smaller parts.

Comment: Yes, I want a specific model, that could train on 20-150 caracter sentences, and generate similar content. 

Comment: Read about word2vec model. It encodes words to vector space, then it can generate similar ones. The variation that you look for i sentence2vec, it works similar, but you give sentence as input for model.

Here is tutorial for tensorflow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/word2vec

I didn't use tensorflow implementation. The model implemented in gensim could be more easy to use:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html